# Proper Flag for Modded Minecraft Questions

Tags: support, flags, minecraft

I'm curious as to the correct flag that needs to be raised on Minecraft mod questions. I understand that questions on the usage of mods (ex. How does thing 'x' work in mod 'y') are okay, but questions about crashes and technical support for mods are not allowed.

My question is, what is the proper flag for this? I typically go with "Should Be Closed -> Off-topic Because... -> Questions about Game Design and Development". Is this the correct flagging sequence? I want to be sure, since there is not a specific flag for game mods themselves.

Comment: Note that the reviewers can't see what type of flag you raised (I think). So just flag with any one of the off-topic flags, and the reviewers will pick the correct option.

Comment: Alex i asked this more than a week ago... it's already been answered...

Comment: Also @Alex this question really isn't related to yours, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf it's the same general question, with the same general answers.

Comment: @Alex I really don't see any reason for you to have done this. No one else thought it was similar enough, except for you.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I don't think anyone ***SAW*** it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While @Wipqozn offers a correct solution for *voting to close*, people with under 3k rep cannot vote to close or flag as off topic with custom reasons. Thus, in my opinion, they should just flag as blatantly off topic. Anyone reviewing it will figure out that it is modded Minecraft and VTC with a custom reason.

Comment: That answers it! Does this go for all game mods as well, ex. Bethesda games, etc?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf currently only modded minecraft is off topic. Other modded games aren't specifically off topic per say, though a lot do get closed as too broad.